# ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.util.StackLocator$FqcnCallerLocator on spring boot 2.3.4 and log4j 2.13.3

Tags: spring, spring-boot, log4j

I'm trying to run log4j 2.13.3(latest release) with spring boot 2.3.4.RELEASE (latest release), but I'm getting the following error when starting my app:

```
mix-data-collector_1     | ------------------------------------------------------------------------
mix-data-collector_1     | OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option PermSize; support was removed in 8.0
mix-data-collector_1     | DB update completed
mix-data-collector_1     | DB migration finished
mix-data-collector_1     | Start Mix Data Collector---------------------------------------------
mix-data-collector_1     | Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5555
mix-data-collector_1     | Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
mix-data-collector_1     |      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
mix-data-collector_1     |      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
mix-data-collector_1     |      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
mix-data-collector_1     |      at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
mix-data-collector_1     |      at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
mix-data-collector_1     loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
mix-data-collector_1     |      at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
mix-data-collector_1     |      at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
mix-data-collector_1     | Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/util/StackLocator$FqcnCallerLocator
mix-data-collector_1     |      at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.StackLocator.<clinit>(StackLocator.java:37)
mix-data-collector_1     |      at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.StackLocatorUtil.<clinit>(StackLocatorUtil.java:33)
mix-data-collector_1     |      at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:133)
mix-data-collector_1     |      at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:228)
mix-data-collector_1     |      at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
mix-data-collector_1     |      at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:174)
mix-data-collector_1     |      at org.springframework.boot.logging.log4j2.Log4J2LoggingSystem.getLoggerContext(Log4J2LoggingSystem.java:305)
mix-data-collector_1     |      at org.springframework.boot.logging.log4j2.Log4J2LoggingSystem.beforeInitialize(Log4J2LoggingSystem.java:145)
mix-data-collector_1     |      at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationStartingEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:232)
mix-data-collector_1     |      at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:213)
mix-data-collector_1     |      at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
mix-data-collector_1     |      at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
mix-data-collector_1     |      at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
mix-data-collector_1     |      at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
mix-data-collector_1     |      at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.starting(EventPublishingRunListener.java:74)
mix-data-collector_1     |      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.starting(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:47)
mix-data-collector_1     |      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305)
mix-data-collector_1     |      at ch.sbb.esta.openshift.gracefullshutdown.GracefulshutdownSpringApplication.run(GracefulshutdownSpringApplication.java:21)
mix-data-collector_1     |      at com.nuance.core.mix.data.collector.Application.main(Application.java:38)
mix-data-collector_1     |      ... 8 more
mix-data-collector_1     | Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.util.StackLocator$FqcnCallerLocator
mix-data-collector_1     |      at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
mix-data-collector_1     |      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
mix-data-collector_1     |      at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:93)
mix-data-collector_1     |      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
mix-data-collector_1     |      ... 27 more
mix-data-collector_mix-data-collector_1 exited with code 1loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
mix-data-collector_1     |      at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
mix-data-collector_1     |      at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
mix-data-collector_1     | Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/util/StackLocator$FqcnCallerLocator
mix-data-collector_1     |      at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.StackLocator.<clinit>(StackLocator.java:37)
mix-data-collector_1     |      at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.StackLocatorUtil.<clinit>(StackLocatorUtil.java:33)
mix-data-collector_1     |      at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:133)
mix-data-collector_1     |      at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:228)
mix-data-collector_1     |      at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
mix-data-collector_1     |      at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:174)
mix-data-collector_1     |      at org.springframework.boot.logging.log4j2.Log4J2LoggingSystem.getLoggerContext(Log4J2LoggingSystem.java:305)
mix-data-collector_1     |      at org.springframework.boot.logging.log4j2.Log4J2LoggingSystem.beforeInitialize(Log4J2LoggingSystem.java:145)
mix-data-collector_1     |      at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationStartingEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:232)
mix-data-collector_1     |      at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:213)
mix-data-collector_1     |      at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
mix-data-collector_1     |      at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
mix-data-collector_1     |      at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
mix-data-collector_1     |      at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
mix-data-collector_1     |      at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.starting(EventPublishingRunListener.java:74)
mix-data-collector_1     |      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.starting(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:47)
mix-data-collector_1     |      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305)
mix-data-collector_1     |      at ch.sbb.esta.openshift.gracefullshutdown.GracefulshutdownSpringApplication.run(GracefulshutdownSpringApplication.java:21)
mix-data-collector_1     |      at com.nuance.core.mix.data.collector.Application.main(Application.java:38)
mix-data-collector_1     |      ... 8 more
mix-data-collector_1     | Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.util.StackLocator$FqcnCallerLocator
mix-data-collector_1     |      at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
mix-data-collector_1     |      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
mix-data-collector_1     |      at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:93)
mix-data-collector_1     |      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
mix-data-collector_1     |      ... 27 more
mix-data-collector_mix-data-collector_1 exited with code 1
```

My maven dependencies look like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>${log4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>${log4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

With log4j 2.11.2 the app starts ok (so there is something that got changed in the latest log4j version), but i need to move to version 2.13.3 in order to mitigate some security issues.
Any idea how i can solve this problems?

Thanks
[image]

latest dependencies:
[image]

Comment: Remove the `org.apache.logging.log4j` dependencies, add `log4j2.version` in your properties. ALso Spring Boot 2.3.4 itself already includes Log4j2 2.13.3 as a dependency.

Comment: I've removed the  org.apache.logging.log4j dependencies, add added the log4j2.version, I've recompiled but I'm still getting the same error during startup

Comment: You don't need the version as Spring Boot already uses the version you want. See [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/2.3.x/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/build.gradle#L1009). If that isn't the version that is included then something else must be overriding it.

Comment: I've removed the version from my properties, but still seeing the same error . And from what i can see there is no other log4j version available in my project. So it has to be something  with this 2.13.3 version IMO.

Comment: Clear your repository and redownload, could be a borked jar.

Comment: I've cleaned up my .m2/repository (rm -Rf)  folder, added the -U to my maven build, but I'm still seeing the error . During the maven build I can see the all the dependencies being downloaded, so the cleanup was done properly.

Comment: A very similar issue has appeared in Quarkus too, see https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/11644. The error there is `Caused by: ... failed to access class org.apache.logging.log4j.util.StackLocator$FqcnCallerLocator ...`

Answer (score 1):

OK I've found my problem. It seems there was also a spring maven plugin dependency that was causing the problem. Thanks for the help

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Please could you provide the info on what was the issue and how you resolved it

Comment: Just make sure all your spring related dependencies are up to date.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the same issue by upgrading log4j-code dependency to version 2.14.1